# I want my div to be 100% of my parent div using styled component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want my NavDiv styled component to be 100% of my Wrapper styled component but it's not workong as expected. Height can only be set using **px** unit, Units such as **percentage, em, rem** doesn't seems to work

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
`

const NavDiv = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 4em 2em;
`
```

App Component

```
const App = () => {
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                <Navbar></Navbar>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
```

NavBar component

```
const Navbar = props => {
    return (
        <NavDiv>
            
        </NavDiv>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `styled-component` problem but `css` problem. Property `height: 100%` won't work unless parent has `height` property too and `min-height` doesn't do the trick.

```css
.wrapper {
    min-width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh; /* I've used height instead of min-height */
}

.nav-div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 4em 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper><div class=nav-div></div></div>
```